# Including shared example from rspec inside of cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

The end goal is to include the shared_examples.rb which is included in rails_helper.rb. shared_examples.rb is a copy of this file

https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor/blob/master/lib/devise_two_factor/spec_helpers/two_factor_authenticatable_shared_examples.rb

I want to reference the shared_examples.rb in my cucumber test so I can use the method `it_behaves_like 'two_factor_authenticatable'`

I have the following folder structure:

Updated to include @morissetcl suggested structure

```
features
    step_definitions
        sample_step.rb
    support
        env.rb
    sample.feature

spec
    models
        user_spec.rb
    support
        shared_examples
            shared_example.rb
    rails_helper.rb
    spec_helper.rb
```

Both the features and spec folders are at the root of my rails project.

I am trying to include inside the sample_step.rb file the rails_helper.rb which is located in the spec folder.

I tried using different types of require as shown below inside the sample_step.rb file.

require 'spec/spec_helpers/shared_examples'

require '../../spec/spec_helpers/shared_examples'

require_relative '../../spec/spec_helpers/shared_examples'

I keep getting the following error

`` undefined method `it_behaves_like' for main:Object (NoMethodError) ``

Comment: Good practice will be to place your `shared_example` inside the support folder `spec/support/shared_examples/the_name_of_your_shared.rb` and after in your `rails_helper` add the following line `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}` which will be used to load your file (in this way you don't need to require something). Moreover I guess it's confusing to use `spec_helper` as folder.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did make the change you provided, however, my shared example still cannot find `it_behaves_like` method. Here is a snippet of the error:   `undefined method it_behaves_like for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x00007fe383683968> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Maybe the real question to ask is does cucumber allow inclusion of shared examples from rspec? The shared_example is an rspec shared example.

Answer (score 0):

`it_behaves_like` is rspec specific. What it does is allow one spec to run another spec for a particular object, so that is not going to work in Cucumber.

What you need to do is have a test suite that has some cukes and some specs. You cover the two factor authentication in detail in rspec, and if you have to always use two factor authentication to login in your cukes you need to write a helper method so you can do that.

To do this I would do the following

1. Write some step definitions to support login, that delegate the work to a helper method.
2. Write the helper method
3. Have the helper method call additional methods to support two factor auth
4. Add the helper methods to cucumber's world object so they can be called in a step def

So

```
# features/step_defintions/login
module LoginStepHelper
  def login(user: )
    login_fill_form_and_submit(user: user)
    login_two_factor(user: user)
    submit_form

  end

  def login_fill_form_and_submit(user: )
    fill_in :email, user.email
    fill_in :password, user.password
  end

  def login_two_factor(user: )
    code = retrieve_2factor_code(user: user)
    fill_in :2factor, code
  end

  ...

end
World(LoginStepHeler)
```

So now you have to work out how the test can get the 2factor code. 
Once you have this done you have a tool your step definitions can use to login, so you can write things like

```
Given 'I am logged in' do
  login user: @i
end

Given 'I login as Fred' do
  login user: @fred
end

...
```

note: how many step defs can use your helper method.

You can find more detail about this approach here https://github.com/diabolo/cuke_up which includes details about how to create the test-users that we are passing into the login function in the above code

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. So I sort of followed what you were saying. The way I got it to work was in the step for cucumber where I needed to login using two factor I had to replicate how the shared example setup the data before running a successful two factor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was using some of the suggestions that @diabolist made. I looked into the shared examples file: https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor/blob/master/lib/devise_two_factor/spec_helpers/two_factor_authenticatable_shared_examples.rb

I then used the #validate_and_consume_otp! scenario and setup the data using the info in the before :each block.

The result was as so in my cucumber spec:

```
When('I fill in the login form with two factor code') do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.current)
  otp_secret = '2z6hxkdwi3uvrnpn'
  @user.otp_secret = otp_secret
  otp = ROTP::TOTP.new(otp_secret).at(Time.now)
  @user.save # <- This is important to save it so the user has the otp you will pass
  Timecop.return

  fill_in 'user_email', with: 'user@example.com'
  fill_in 'user_password', with: 'password'
  fill_in 'user_otp_attempt', with: otp
  click_button 'Login'
end
```

The setup can be cleaned up and put into a method just as @diabolist described so it can be reused by other tests.